# Css Image Resize based on height

Tags: html, css, image

I am aware of resizing images bases on width:

```
img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

or

```
img{
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
}
```

Is there a way to do it by height?  This does not seem to work:

```
img{
  height: 500px;
  width: auto;
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: The percentages you use is a percentage of the container that the element is in.  You CAN do a height percentage or actual px should work as well, just don't specify the width?

Comment: It seems working to me: http://jsbin.com/sesul/1/edit

Comment: can you add some HTML code where this doesnt seem to be working ? :o

Answer (score 5):

From what you have shown it should work fine.

```
img{
  height: 500px;
  width: auto;
}
```

The above code does work, make sure it's not in a restrictive div, or another style is overwriting it

Answer (score 1):

You in fact can explicitly declare a height of 100px (for example) with `height: 100px;`. If your code isn't working this way, there may be something else outside of this context that is causing the problem.